# rxjs/Rx has no export member forkjoin

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm trying to use ForkJoin...it can't find forkjoin in node_modules/rxjs/Rx and throws error forkjoin is not member of rxjs/Rx.

```
import { forkJoin } from 'rxjs';
ngOnInit() {
      forkJoin([
      this.vehicleService.getMakes(),
      this.vehicleService.getFeatures(),
      this.vehicleService.getVehicle(this.vehicle.id)]).subscribe(data => {
      this.makes = data[0];
      this.features = data[1];
      this.vehicle = data[2];
      }, err => {
        if (err.status == 404)
          this.router.navigate(['/home']);
      });
```

Comment: What is the rxjs version you are using?

Comment: "rxjs": "^5.5.6"

Comment: try this: `import {forkJoin} from "rxjs/observable/forkJoin";`

Comment: @Ashish....it is working now....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a typo and you need to import from

```
import {forkJoin} from "rxjs/observable/forkJoin";
```

Answer (score 0):

It's `forkJoin` and not `forkjoin`.

```
import { forkJoin } from 'rxjs';
```

should work.